# Parsley.js validates all forms in jquerymobile1.4.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, parsley.js

Am building a jquerymobile app that has multiple forms on a page like so:

```
    <form id="remember_form" action="#" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" parsley-validate>
            <input type="email" name="rem_email" required parsley-error-container="#remember_validation" parsley-error-message="Email address is required" title="Email required" placeholder="Email" data-icon="x" class="login_controls">
            <div style="padding-bottom:10px;"></div>
            <a href="#" style="text-shadow:none;" id="remem_psswd" class="enviar">Get Password</a>
        </form>
```

In my js file, i have this:

```
if ($('#remember_form').parsley( 'validate' ) == true){
    $.mobile.changePage('#main');   
}
```

My problem is that parsley.js validates all the forms on the page. How do i prevent this behaviour

Comment: are you using the same id `remember_form` in other pages?

Comment: Am only using it there, I made sure of that

Comment: ok, when do you call `.parsley` validation function? on which event?

Comment: This is normally not possible. Could you share a link (jsfiddle maybe) showing this behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do something like this in js:

```
if ($('#remember_form').parsley( 'validate' ) == true){

}
```

calling parsley( 'validate' ) for each form only validates that form